# Azure Service Bus Queue sending a message in NodeJs to .NET client

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am sending a message from a C# worker to the Queue, then I am getting it on another C# worker and call

`string body = message.GetBody<string>();`

This works and I later de-serialize the string/JSON message.

Now I am trying to send the same message from NodeJS in form of a JSON message. When I try to receive it and

`string body = message.GetBody<string>();`

call this I get an exception saying the input is in incorrect format.

My message object on NodeJS looks like this

```
{
  body: JSON.stringify(message)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it fixed!

By default the .NET Azure Queue library uses a DataContractSerializer and a binary XmlDictionaryWriter to serialize the string message when using

`new BrokeredMessage("my message");`

So instead you need to use this

`new BrokeredMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my message")), true);`

and to read the message in C# you need to use

`string body = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();`

I also stopped wrapping my `JSON.stringify` message in an object and pass it directly to the `sendQueueMessage`. The send message code looks like this now:

`serviceBusService.sendQueueMessage('my_queue', JSON.stringify("my message"), function(error){});`

`JSON.stringify` outputs a UTF8 string so it is fully compatible with the C# code.