# Adding DataContractSerialization to my ServiceBus Queue

Tags: azure, datacontractserializer, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, azure-cloud-services

So, I have a worker role that is currently live and messages are being posted from a variety of sources.

At the moment it's written so that it picks up the messages and then gets the object via:

```
message.GetBody<T>();
```

This works fine, but I'm improving the support side of things, and using that technique bugs me by the way that the object is encoded, it isn't the greatest when looking at the messages in software such as Service Bus Explorer, so I've decided to add a `DataContractSerializer`

My main issue is that the sources that submit the messages to my service bus won't all be released at the same time and I'd like to independantly release my worker role where it will work for both the old sources and those that have the new `DataContractSerializer` implementation.

Basically, my new worker role will now have the following:

```
message.GetBody<T>(new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T)));
```

The problem is that this expects the sources referencing the NuGet package will also have serialized the same way.

I've thought of 2 methods of resolving this which to be honest, I'm not too pleased with:

The first being a delivery count failure watcher, and on attempt n, revert to the older functionality (which isn't nice).

The second being a separate worker, but again, this stinks.

Does anyone have any ideas or guidance on how I can best achieve this?

Comment: [maybe this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33892231/5153058) Check this one maybe this help you

Comment: That's just another way of encoding the message, which I've already achieved

Comment: Is there anything that is going to be unique to the different sources (new and old) so that you can go for simple identification of the client and redirect accordingly?

Second idea is, what if you serialize the message when you receive them in the worker role regardless of the type (new and old) then deserialize it. I wonder if that'd work.

Comment: You could use the Properties collection for the message to include information on how the body has been serialized. Your worker role can call the relevant GetBody based on the value of the property or if the property doesn't exist it's an old source.